# Set manually created span as parent to following spans in Opentelemetry

Tags: javascript, cypress, open-telemetry

Help linking all spans created by OpenTelemetry to a parent span that is created manually

I have registered the following instrumentation for my frontend code:

```
const resource = new Resource({
  [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME]: 'frontend_app',
});
const provider = new WebTracerProvider({
  resource,
});
const exporter = new OTLPTraceExporter();

provider.addSpanProcessor(new BatchSpanProcessor(exporter));
provider.register({
  contextManager: new ZoneContextManager(),
});

export const tracer = provider.getTracer('fe-tracer');

registerInstrumentations({
  instrumentations: [
    getWebAutoInstrumentations({
      // load custom configuration for xml-http-request instrumentation
      "@opentelemetry/instrumentation-xml-http-request": {
        propagateTraceHeaderCorsUrls: [/.+/g],
      },
      // load custom configuration for fetch instrumentation
      "@opentelemetry/instrumentation-fetch": {
        propagateTraceHeaderCorsUrls: [/.+/g],
      },
    }),
  ],
});
```

Beside this I have Cypress tests for this application, so in each test I manually create a span

```
const activeSpan = tracer.startSpan(
  Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.ctx.currentTest.fullTitle()
);
```

After the tests ends of course I end the span:

```
activeSpan.end();
```

What I expect to see is basically all the spans that are created after the `activeSpan` should be children of it, but that is not the case, in Jaeger I see one span that is created from the test itself and all the rest are nested under a separate span...
I tried to do the following:

```
trace.setSpan(context.active(), activeSpan);
```

But again no luck, same result in Jaeger, 2 different spans

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the correct way to do it but it worked for me.  The main thing was to wrap the call to the external library with the current span context using the `with`.

```js
    import optl from '@opentelemetry/api';
    import { tracing } from '@private/tracing-library';
    import { registerInstrumentations } from '@opentelemetry/instrumentation';
    import { TediousInstrumentation } from '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-tedious';

    const tracer = tracing;
    registerInstrumentations({
        tracer,
        instrumentations: [
            new TediousInstrumentation()
        ]
    });

...
    function foo(arg1, parentSpan) {
       ctx = optl.trace.setSpan(optl.context.active(), parentSpan);
       funSpan = tracer.startSpan('span_name', { kind: optl.SpanKind.CLIENT }, ctx);
        try {
        // surround auto instrumentated code with the new context created in the function
          await optl.context.with(optl.trace.setSpan(optl.context.active(), funSpan), async () => {
             return await autoInstrumentatedFunction();
        } catch (err) {
            funSpan.recordException(err.message);
            funSpan.setStatus({
                code: optl.SpanStatusCode.ERROR,
                message: { timestamp: new Date().toISOString(), status: 'Error', title: 'Error Title', details: err.message }
            });
        } finally {
           funSpan.end();
        } 
    }
```